# Error in while in mysql

Tags: mysql, while-loop

I want to create function in mysql for :

> ```
> Input: 7589586586     Output:  (758) 958-6586
> Input: 758ABC6586     Output: (758) 222-6586  
> Input: 758ABC65       Output: Invalid Formats (like mobile keypad)
> ```

The following mysql code gives errors:

```
   DELIMITER $$
    CREATE FUNCTION fn_bhagyashreed_phonenumber(input varchar(20))
    RETURNS varchar(50)
    LANGUAGE SQL
    BEGIN
    DECLARE compare varchar(30) ;            
    DECLARE cnt INT;
    DECLARE varout varchar(30);
    DECLARE val varchar(30);
    DECLARE Phoutput varchar(50);
    DECLARE var INT;
    set var=LENGTH(input);
    SET compare ='';
    SET  cnt =1;
    SET varout ='';
    SET val = '';
    SET Phoutput ='';
       if((var<>10)||(input NOT REGEXP '^[[:alnum:]]+$' )) THEN
        set Phoutput='Invalid Format';
        else if((LENGTH(input))=10) THEN
        begin
        IF (input REGEXP '^[[:alnum:]]+$' ) THEN
        begin
        while (cnt<=10) DO
            set compare=substring(input,cnt,1);
                if compare in('a','b','c','2') THEN
                    set val=2;
                else if compare in('d','e','f','3') THEN
                    set val=3;
                else if compare in('g','h','i','4') THEN
                        set val=4;
                else if compare in('j','k','l','5') THEN
                        set val=5;
                else if compare in('m','n','o','6') THEN
                        set val=6;
                else if compare in('p','q','r','s','7') THEN
                        set val=7;
                else if compare in('t','u','v','8') THEN
                        set val=8;
                else if compare in('w','x','y','z','9') THEN
                        set val=9;
                else if (compare ='1') THEN
                        set val=1;
                else if(compare ='0') THEN
                        set val=0;
        end if;
                        set varout = CONCAT(varout,val);
                        set cnt=cnt+1;
    end while;
    set Phoutput = CONCAT('(',SUBSTR(varout,1,3),')',' ',SUBSTR(varout,4,3),'-',SUBSTR(varout,7,4));

    end IF;
    end if;
    return Phoutput;
    end;
    $$
    DELIMITER ;
```

The error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'while; set Phoutput = CONCAT('(',SUBSTR(varout,1,3),')','
>   ',SUBSTR(varout,4,' at line 65

Comment: What is the exact error message? Should we guess?

Comment: and dis error stmt in phpmyadmin:

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'while; set Phoutput = CONCAT('(',SUBSTR(varout,1,3),')',' ',SUBSTR(varout,4,' at line 65

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cleaned up your code SIGNIFICANTLY:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION fn_phone_number(input VARCHAR(20)) RETURNS VARCHAR(14) LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN
    DECLARE cnt INT;
    DECLARE chr CHAR(1);
    DECLARE number VARCHAR(10);

    SET cnt = 1;
    SET number = '';

    IF ((LENGTH(input) = 10) && (input REGEXP '^[[:alnum:]]+$')) THEN
        WHILE (cnt <= 10) DO
            SET chr = SUBSTR(input,cnt,1);

            IF chr IN('a','b','c','2') THEN
                SET number = CONCAT(number,'2');
            ELSEIF chr IN('d','e','f','3') THEN
                SET number = CONCAT(number,'3');
            ELSEIF chr IN('g','h','i','4') THEN
                SET number = CONCAT(number,'4');
            ELSEIF chr IN('j','k','l','5') THEN
                SET number = CONCAT(number,'5');
            ELSEIF chr IN('m','n','o','6') THEN
                SET number = CONCAT(number,'6');
            ELSEIF chr IN('p','q','r','s','7') THEN
                SET number = CONCAT(number,'7');
            ELSEIF chr IN('t','u','v','8') THEN
                SET number = CONCAT(number,'8');
            ELSEIF chr IN('w','x','y','z','9') THEN
                SET number = CONCAT(number,'9');
            ELSEIF chr IN('0','1') THEN
                SET number = CONCAT(number,chr);
            END IF;

            SET cnt = cnt + 1;
        END WHILE;
        RETURN CONCAT('(', SUBSTR(number,1,3), ') ', SUBSTR(number,4,3), '-', SUBSTR(number,7,4));
    ELSE
        RETURN 'Invalid Format';
    END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Issues with syntax in your code:

1. There is no `ELSE IF` instead there is `ELSEIF`
2. You twice opened `BEGIN ... END` block but never terminated it. In fact you there was no need in using them at all.

A syntactically correct and bit streamlined version of your function might look like this

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION fn_bhagyashreed_phonenumber(input VARCHAR(20))
RETURNS VARCHAR(50)
BEGIN
    DECLARE compare VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT '';            
    DECLARE cnt INT DEFAULT 1;
    DECLARE varout VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT '';
    DECLARE val VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT '';
    DECLARE Phoutput VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT '';
    DECLARE var INT;

    SET var = LENGTH(input);

    IF var <> 10 OR input NOT REGEXP '^[[:alnum:]]+$' THEN
        SET Phoutput = 'Invalid Format';
    ELSE
        WHILE cnt <= 10 DO
            SET compare = SUBSTRING(input, cnt, 1);
            IF compare IN('a','b','c','2') THEN
                SET val=2;
            ELSEIF compare IN('d','e','f','3') THEN
                SET val=3;
            ELSEIF compare IN('g','h','i','4') THEN
                SET val=4;
            ELSEIF compare IN('j','k','l','5') THEN
                SET val=5;
            ELSEIF compare IN('m','n','o','6') THEN
                SET val=6;
            ELSEIF compare IN('p','q','r','s','7') THEN
                SET val=7;
            ELSEIF compare IN('t','u','v','8') THEN
                SET val=8;
            ELSEIF compare IN('w','x','y','z','9') THEN
                SET val=9;
            ELSEIF compare = '1' THEN
                SET val=1;
            ELSEIF compare = '0' THEN
                SET val=0;
            END IF;
            SET varout = CONCAT(varout,val);
            SET cnt = cnt + 1;
        END WHILE;
        SET Phoutput = CONCAT('(',SUBSTR(varout,1,3),')',' ',SUBSTR(varout,4,3),'-',SUBSTR(varout,7,4));
    END IF;
    RETURN Phoutput;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Let's try it out:

```
SELECT fn_bhagyashreed_phonenumber(value) phone
FROM
(
  SELECT '7589586586' value UNION ALL
  SELECT '758ABC6586' UNION ALL
  SELECT '758ABC65' 
) q
```

Output:

```
|          PHONE |
|----------------|
| (758) 958-6586 |
| (758) 222-6586 |
| Invalid Format |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d18fb/2)** demo

Comment: Thank You sooo very much.. needed dis asap .. :)